# Function format number and how to use it in sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle, numbers, format

For oracle,

If I have a table A with data in **`number`** (such as price), how to **write a function** to format a **`number(10,2)`** to 9,9999.99 (<< obvious format).

And then how to use this function in SQL statement for displaying the data in table A.

Thank you.

----- UPDATE -----
From kindly suggestions below, yes, I should not treat numbers in this way.
But I highly want to accomplish the task above

Here I come with the function

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Fmt_num(N1 in NUMBER)
    RETURN CHAR
    IS
    BEGIN
    RETURN TO_CHAR(N1,'FM9,9999.99');
    END;
    /
```

And I can use this with the SQL statement as follow

```
    SELECT Fmt_num(price) from A;
```

It works ! However, Can anyone fixes the function above to let it works with "a number (10,2)"? Just this condition only. Thank you for your anticipate in this noob question. :)

Comment: **[Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227039/oracle-how-do-i-convert-hex-to-decimal-in-oracle-sql)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [TO_CHAR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#i34510) function.

```
select to_char(price, 'FM9,999,999.99')
  from A;
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. Btw, this is a query. Is there possible to create a function first and then pull that function into this query?

Comment: You can do it, but I would not recommend it. Encode the formatting in your end-user application instead.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. If you don't mind can you show me the example (for my obvious task), would be a good knowledge for me. :) Thank you