# Oracle number format model maximum length

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I run into a peculiar limit in `X` [number format element](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements004.htm) used in `to_number`and in `to_char` when I was [converting hexadecimal numbers to decimal numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1227039/272735).

It looks like number format model has maximum length of 63 characters but I can't find the limit mentioned in [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements004.htm). E.g. the maximum length of datetime format model is mentioned:

> The total length of a datetime format model cannot exceed 22 characters.

With 63 `X`es:

```
SQL> select to_number('A', rpad('X', 63, 'X')) from dual;

TO_NUMBER('A',RPAD('X',63,'X'))
-------------------------------
                             10
```

With 64 `X`es:

```
SQL> select to_number('A', rpad('X', 64, 'X')) from dual;
select to_number('A', rpad('X', 64, 'X')) from dual
                      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01481: invalid number format model
```

I have only tried `X` format element as it is relevant for my current task.

**The questions:**

1. Is this a known number format model limitation that is just missing from documentation ?
2. How do I convert a 64 (and longer) digit length hexadecimal number to a decimal number ?

Comment: What is the purpose of such conversion? Do some arithmetic with number values or just store and show?

Comment: @ThinkJet This is a data load from a 3rd party legacy hardware device that has been running since mid 90's. A new version introduced these bigger hexadecimal fields. The conversion was done because it was always done - nobody here knows why. After cleaning some dusty corners we realised the end system no more uses this specific performance indicator so we could just drop it (what a relief). It also looks like the purpose of the indicator has changed at some point and it contains several segments that has to be decoded separately but nobody told us. Oh, the joys of a maintenance programmer !

Comment: Ok. I sympathise with you about maintenance issues. If sometime later you meet this indicator again, take a look at [`rawtohex`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions131.htm) and [`hextoraw`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions131.htm) functions to make conversion and [`UTL_RAW`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_raw.htm) package to extract specific readings and perform bit-level operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's beyond **precision** NUMBER can go. More info in official documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00222

Comment: I don't think so. According to `bc` the largest 64 digit hexadecimal number in decimal is approx. `1.2 x 10^77` that should fit very well to the range of Oracle `number` (max value: `1.0 x 10^126 - 1`).

Comment: @user272735 Absolute value is different thing. Maximum number of significant digits is `precision` and [limited to 39 or 40 decimal digits](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00222) for `number` data type.

Comment: @ThinkJet Ah, but of course ! Only after your comment I realised what I missed when I read the documentation. igr please edit your post so I can upvote.