# PLSQL: generate next unique key of a specific size

Tags: algorithm, oracle, plsql

I have a table in which there is a primary key named **CODE** of Type **VARCHAR(3)**. The problem is that all the available values from 000,001 .... 999 are used in different records. As the field CODE is in varchar format so we can have alphabets along with digits.

Is there any algorithm or function in plsql through which we can uniformly generate unique keys of length 3 which includes alphabets as well. Note that we cannot change the field size as it is referenced in so many other tables.

Comment: Either if you implement the algorithm that generate keys which include non-numeric characters, soon you're going to run out of keys because your key length of **3**. Note, that you **can** change the field size even if it is referenced in many other tables.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://forums.oracle.com/message/2829305

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this solution
generate alpha-numeric code based on oracle sequence
please check code

```
declare
    l_val      number := 255; -- SQN_TMP_01.nextval;
    l_base     number := 62; -- 00azAZ
    l_base_str varchar2(62) := '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    l_res      number;
    l_final    varchar2(100);
begin
    loop
        -- init numberic value
        l_val   := SQN_TMP_01.nextval;
        l_final := null;
        dbms_output.put_line(l_val);

        -- convert value to alphanumeric code
        loop
            l_res   := mod(l_val, l_base);
            l_final := substr(l_base_str, l_res + 1, 1) || l_final;
            exit when l_val - l_res = 0;
            l_val := trunc((l_val - l_res) / l_base);
            dbms_output.put_line('res = ' || l_res || ' l_val = ' || l_val || ' final: "' || l_final || '"');
        end loop;

        dbms_output.put_line('check final: "' || l_final || '"');
        -- exclude full numeric result as already used
        exit when trim(translate(l_final, '0123456789', ' ')) is not null;
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line('final string: "' || l_final || '"');
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should almost certainly migrate your field to an integer type.  If that's impossible then it should be possible to convert to a larger char field as bpgergo suggests.

If you're really, really stuck with a 3 character limit you could use to_char(id, 'xxx') to convert to hex, as in: [Oracle: How do I convert hex to decimal in Oracle SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227039/oracle-how-do-i-convert-hex-to-decimal-in-oracle-sql)

This would give you up to 4096 entries.  It should be possible (but more complex) to use base64 (up to 262,144 entries), or go up to base 128 (2,097,152), or just use the whole field as a 3 byte unsigned integer if you don't care about the raw data being printable characters (16,777,216).