# Oracle convert column which is varchar / hex to numeric format after loading data from xlsx file

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I loaded an Excel file into a table and found out that some data in my varchar2 field is in HEX format.

When I execute my query, I have no problem, but when I try to insert my data into another table with a number format it does not work.

This query shows which column is in HEX format :

```
SELECT qty, TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(qty, CHR(32), '')) as nbkg, RAWTOHEX(qty) as Graphics 
FROM (
  SELECT nvl(qty, 0) AS qty,
    case
        when pkg_tools.f_is_number(qty) = 1 then 'OK'
        else 'NOK'
    end kg
  FROM table
) 
WHERE kg = 'NOK';

*qty is a varchar2(50)
```

My output :

```
qty  nbkg  Graphics
---  ----  --------
10 009,000    10009,000    3130203030392C303030  -- work
3 250,00    3250,00    33203235302C3030   -- work
1 000,00    1000,00    31203030302C3030   -- work
1 230,00    1 230,00    31A03233302C3030  -- Not work
1 750,00    1 750,00    31A03735302C3030  -- Not work
4 000,00    4 000,00    34A03030302C3030  -- Not work
1 980,00    1 980,00    31A03938302C3030  -- Not work
1 050,00    1 050,00    31A03035302C3030  -- Not work
1 050,00    1 050,00    31A03035302C3030  -- Not work
1 000,00    1 000,00    31A03030302C3030  -- Not work
39 950,00    39 950,00    3339A03935302C3030 -- Not work
3 000,00    3 000,00    33A03030302C3030  
...
...
```

I am trying to convert it into a number before inserting my data :

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(qty, CHR(32), '')) 
FROM table;

SELECT TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(qty, '\s'))
FROM table;
```

and I am getting an error : 
`ORA-01722: invalid number`

How can i convert this column which is varchar / hex to numeric format?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle: How do I convert hex to decimal in Oracle SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227039/oracle-how-do-i-convert-hex-to-decimal-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: I saw this one and it does not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a Format mask and NLS information by using `to_number` function.

so it could look like:

```
select to_number('1 250,000','999G999G999D99999','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='', ''') as n
from dual
```

if you check the hex value e.g. `31A03030302C3030` you can see the `A0` on the second Position. that is displayed as empty string but is `&nbsp;` and not a space that has a hex Position 20 in ASCII table. So just replace that 160 with 32

```
to_number(replace('1 250,000',chr(160),chr(32)),'999G999G999D99999','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='', ''') as n
```

**result:**

```
n
------
1250
```

Comment: does not work, I edited my code and add a Graphics column, to show that I do not have only a varchar in my column, it's strange

Comment: what doen't work? its not clear what your a trying to do.

Comment: I already try your solution and i have the same error ORA-01722. I want to insert data but  i can't convert 'qty' column to number because if you see my Graphics column you will understand that's not a varchar it's a hex for some of data :
`insert into tab (....)
SELECT cl1, 
    TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(qty, CHR(32), '')) as cl2,
    cl3,
    .... 
FROM table;`

Comment: ok i see, there `&nbsp;` try to replace  char chr(160) with 32

Comment: This one works well `TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(REPLACE(qty, CHR(160), ''), CHR(32), ''))`
because i have chr(160) and chr(32) in my data.
omg that makes me crazy,Thx hotfix;)